# Single Responsibility Principle(SRP) and class structure of my rpg looks "weird"

Tags: c#, design-patterns, solid-principles

I'm making a role playing game just for fun and to learn more about the SOLID principles. One of the first things I'm focusing on is SRP. I have a "Character" class that represents a character in the game. It has things like Name, Health, Mana, AbilityScores, etc.

Now, normally I would also put methods in my Character class so it would look something like this...

```
   public class Character
   {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public int Health { get; set; }
      public int Mana { get; set; }
      public Dictionary<AbilityScoreEnum, int>AbilityScores { get; set; }

      // base attack bonus depends on character level, attribute bonuses, etc
      public static void GetBaseAttackBonus();  
      public static int RollDamage();
      public static TakeDamage(int amount);
   }
```

But because of SRP I've decided to move all the methods out into a separate class. I named that class "CharacterActions" and now the method signatures look like this...

```
public class CharacterActions
{
    public static void GetBaseAttackBonus(Character character);
    public static int RollDamage(Character character);
    public static TakeDamage(Character character, int amount);
}
```

Notice that I now have to include the Character object I am using in all my CharacterActions methods. Is this the right way to go about leveraging SRP? It seems to go completely against the OOP concept of encapsulation.

Or am I doing something completely wrong here?

ONE thing I do like about this is that my Character class is very clear on what it does, it simply represents a Character object.

Comment: SRP is Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Update** - I've redone my answer because, after a half-night's sleep, I really didn't feel that my previous answer was very good.

To see an example of the SRP in action, let's consider a very simple character:

```
public abstract class Character
{
    public virtual void Attack(Character target)
    {
        int damage = Random.Next(1, 20);
        target.TakeDamage(damage);
    }

    public virtual void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        HP -= damage;
        if (HP <= 0)
            Die();
    }

    protected virtual void Die()
    {
        // Doesn't matter what this method does right now
    }

    public int HP { get; private set; }
    public int MP { get; private set; }
    protected Random Random { get; private set; }
}
```

OK, so this would be a pretty boring RPG.  But this class *makes sense*.  Everything here is directly related to the `Character`.  Every method is either an action performed by, or performed on the `Character`.  Hey, games are easy!

Let's focus on the `Attack` part and try to make this halfway interesting:

```
public abstract class Character
{
    public const int BaseHitChance = 30;

    public virtual void Attack(Character target)
    {
        int chanceToHit = Dexterity + BaseHitChance;
        int hitTest = Random.Next(100);
        if (hitTest < chanceToHit)
        {
            int damage = Strength * 2 + Weapon.DamageRating;
            target.TakeDamage(damage);
        }
    }

    public int Strength { get; private set; }
    public int Dexterity { get; private set; }
    public Weapon Weapon { get; set; }
}
```

Now we're getting somewhere.  The character sometimes misses, and damage/hit go up with level (assuming that STR increases as well).  Jolly good, but this is still pretty dull because it doesn't take into account anything about the target.  Let's see if we can fix that:

```
public void Attack(Character target)
{
    int chanceToHit = CalculateHitChance(target);
    int hitTest = Random.Next(100);
    if (hitTest < chanceToHit)
    {
        int damage = CalculateDamage(target);
        target.TakeDamage(damage);
    }
}

protected int CalculateHitChance(Character target)
{
    return Dexterity + BaseHitChance - target.Evade;
}

protected int CalculateDamage(Character target)
{
    return Strength * 2 + Weapon.DamageRating - target.Armor.ArmorRating -
        (target.Toughness / 2);
}
```

At this point, the question should already be forming in your mind:  *Why is the `Character` responsible for calculating its own damage against a target?  Why does it even have that ability?*  There's something intangibly *weird* about what this class is doing, but at this point it's still sort of ambiguous.  Is it really worth refactoring just to move a few lines of code out of the `Character` class?  Probably not.

But let's look at what happens when we start adding more features - say from a typical 1990s-era RPG:

```
protected int CalculateDamage(Character target)
{
    int baseDamage = Strength * 2 + Weapon.DamageRating;
    int armorReduction = target.Armor.ArmorRating;
    int physicalDamage = baseDamage - Math.Min(armorReduction, baseDamage);
    int pierceDamage = (int)(Weapon.PierceDamage / target.Armor.PierceResistance);
    int elementDamage = (int)(Weapon.ElementDamage /
        target.Armor.ElementResistance[Weapon.Element]);
    int netDamage = physicalDamage + pierceDamage + elementDamage;
    if (HP < (MaxHP * 0.1))
        netDamage *= DesperationMultiplier;
    if (Status.Berserk)
        netDamage *= BerserkMultiplier;
    if (Status.Weakened)
        netDamage *= WeakenedMultiplier;
    int randomDamage = Random.Next(netDamage / 2);
    return netDamage + randomDamage;
}
```

This is all fine and dandy but isn't it a little ridiculous to be doing all of this number-crunching in the `Character` class?  And this is a fairly short method; in a real RPG this method might extend well into the hundreds of lines with saving throws and all other manner of nerditude.  Imagine, you bring in a new programmer, and they say: *I got a request for a dual-hit weapon that's supposed to double whatever the damage would normally be; where do I need to make the change?*  And you tell him, *Check the `Character` class.*  **Huh??**

Even worse, maybe the game adds some new wrinkle like, oh I don't know, a backstab bonus, or some other type of environment bonus.  Well how the hell are you supposed to figure that out in the `Character` class?  You'll probably end up calling out to some singleton, like:

```
protected int CalculateDamage(Character target)
{
    // ...
    int backstabBonus = Environment.Current.Battle.IsFlanking(this, target);
    // ...
}
```

Yuck.  This is awful.  Testing and debugging this is going to be a nightmare.  So what do we do?  Take it out of the `Character` class.  The `Character` class should **only** know how to do things that a `Character` would logically know how to do, and calculating the exact damage against a target really isn't one of them.  We'll make a class for it:

```
public class DamageCalculator
{
    public DamageCalculator()
    {
        this.Battle = new DefaultBattle();
        // Better: use an IoC container to figure this out.
    }

    public DamageCalculator(Battle battle)
    {
        this.Battle = battle;
    }

    public int GetDamage(Character source, Character target)
    {
        // ...
    }

    protected Battle Battle { get; private set; }
}
```

Much better.  This class does exactly one thing.  It does what it says on the tin.  We've gotten rid of the singleton dependency, so this class is actually possible to test now, and it *feels* a lot more right, doesn't it?  And now our `Character` can concentrate on `Character` actions:

```
public abstract class Character
{
    public virtual void Attack(Character target)
    {
        HitTest ht = new HitTest();
        if (ht.CanHit(this, target))
        {
            DamageCalculator dc = new DamageCalculator();
            int damage = dc.GetDamage(this, target);
            target.TakeDamage(damage);
        }
    }
}
```

Even now it's a little questionable that one `Character` is directly invoking another `Character`'s `TakeDamage` method, and in reality you'd probably just want the character to "submit" its attack to some sort of battle engine, but I think that part is best left as an exercise to the reader.

---

Now, hopefully, you understand why this:

```
public class CharacterActions
{
    public static void GetBaseAttackBonus(Character character);
    public static int RollDamage(Character character);
    public static TakeDamage(Character character, int amount);
}
```

...is basically useless.  What's wrong with it?

- It doesn't have a clear purpose; generic "actions" are not a **single** responsibility;
- It fails to accomplish anything that a `Character` can't already do by itself;
- It depends entirely on the `Character` and nothing else;
- It will probably require you to expose parts of the `Character` class that you really want private/protected.

The `CharacterActions` class breaks the `Character` encapsulation and adds little to nothing of its own.  The `DamageCalculator` class, on the other hand, provides a new encapsulation and helps to restore the cohesion of the original `Character` class by eliminating all of the unnecessary dependencies and unrelated functionality.  If we want to change something about the way damage is calculated, it's *obvious* where to look.

I'm hoping that this explains the principle better now.

Comment: Have you seen this episode of dimecasts? http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/CastDetails/88 This is where I got the idea from. Basically, they start with a Report class that has methods for Printing a report and formatting a report. By the end of the episode they create a "ReportFormatter" and "ReportPrinter" class. I don't really see the difference between what I am doing and what they did. If you have watched it can you please help me understand how what I am doing is different?

Comment: @mikedev: The idea behind something like a `ReportFormatter` or `ReportPrinter` is that sometimes when one individual action is extremely complex, you want to encapsulate it in its own class to remove some of that complexity from the main entity.  To adapt this to your example, if calculating the attack bonus were a very complicated operation, you might abstract this into an `AttackBonusCalculator` or something similar.  However, simply moving **all** of the actions from the `Character` class into a generic "Actions" class does not add anything particularly useful.  HTH.

Comment: @mikedev: I would add that what @Aaronaught is saying is not remove `GetBaseAttackBonus` from the Character class, but that `AttackBonusCalculator` is called form that method.

Comment: What happens if you want your character to defend as well as attack? Or retreat? You have to add more responsibilities to the class.

Comment: @Si: SRP doesn't mean that the class can only have one method.  Both `Attack` and `Defend` (and `Cast` and `Flee` and `UseItem` and what-have-you) are all actions specific to the `Character` and only the `Character`.  There's no reason why we can't add those to the `Character` class (well, other than the reason that they might depend on the environment, but my revised answer was long enough as is without turning it into an essay on game design...)

Comment: I never said a class should only have one method. But if you choose to make that class responsible for all actions, then the chances that you will have bugs is higher, and change will be harder. For example, if these action methods share fields in the character class and those fields are not initialised correctly at the start of each method.

Comment: @Si: Creating generic "Character Action" classes that depend upon the public/internal fields of the `Character` does nothing to solve that problem, which, mind you, is hardly a real problem - who writes methods that depend on shared fields being initialized by other methods?  I'll repeat this one last time:  **Multiple methods are not multiple responsibilities.**  Each and every one of these methods are character-specific "battle actions" and do not suffer from coupling or interdependency issues.  The actions do **not** need to be moved.

Answer (score 7):

**SRP doesn't mean that a class shouldn't have methods.**  What you've done is created a *data-structure* rather than a *polymorphic object* that.  There are benefits to doing so, but it's probably not intended or needed in this case.

One way you can often tell if an object is violating SRP is to look at the instance variables that the methods within the object use.  If there are groups of methods that use certain instance variables, but not others, that's usually a sign that your object can be split up according the the groups of instance variables.

Also, you probably don't want your methods to be static.  You'll likely want to leverage polymorphism -- the ability to do something different within your methods based on the type of the instance on which the method was called.

For example, would your methods need to change if you had an `ElfCharacter` and a `WizardCharacter`?  If your methods will absolutely never change and are completely self contained, then perhaps static is alright... but even then it makes testing much more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends if your characters behaviour can change. For example, if you wanted the available actions to change (based on something else happening in the RPG) you could go for something like:

```
public interface ICharacter
{
    //...
    IEnumerable<IAction> Actions { get; }
}

public interface IAction
{
    ICharacter Character { get; }
    void Execute();
}

public class BaseAttackBonus : IAction
{
    public BaseAttackBonus(ICharacter character)
    {
        Character = character;
    }

    public ICharacter Character { get; private set; }   

    public void Execute()
    {
        // Get base attack bonus for character...
    }
}
```

This allows your character to have as many actions as you want (meaning you can add/remove actions without changing character class), and each action is responsible for only itself (but knows about the character) and for actions which have more complex requirements, inherit from IAction to add properties, etc. You'd probably want a different return value for Execute, and you may want a queue of actions, but you get the drift.

Note use of ICharacter instead of a Character, since characters may have different properties and behaviour (Warlock, Wizard, etc), but they probably all have actions.

By separating out actions, it also makes testing much easier, since you can now test each action without having to wire up a full character, and with ICharacter you can create your own (mock) character more easily.

Comment: Ha, I was just writing up some sample code with IAction and ICharacter

Comment: Just to be clear, would the "Actions" property in the ICharacter interface contain all the possible actions the ICharacter can perform?

Comment: @mikedev, yes, I was going to write that your character no longer has to be responsible for deciding what actions are possible, or when they are executed. That could be due to something external to the character, such as their environment. So you might consider another class (or two) that are responsible for deciding actions as well as executing them.

Comment: Thank you for the answers so far. Say I add an action to drink a health potion. Now when I do this I need to first check to make sure the character has at least one health potion in their inventory. Where do checks like this go? Would it make sense to put it in a "DrinkPotion : IAction" class or does it make more sense to put this in another class like you mention - one for deciding actions and executing them?

Comment: I really don't think that this level of indirection really adds anything in terms of understanding the SRP.  Yes, it might be good design in some/many situations, but IMO it's just further confounding the overall issue, especially the way this example is presented - it's not at all clear how an `IAction` could depend upon the state of the game when the only class it references is `ICharacter`.

Comment: @mikedev: As long as we're talking about "best practices" anyway, a class should not be named after a verb.  The name `DrinkPotion` implies that the class has no data or state, it's just a procedure, and this is something you want to avoid in OO design.

Comment: @Aaronaught, if a class is responsible for attacking, defending, walking, running, etc. then it has more than one responsibility right? By abstracting IAction, we can extend it without having to rely on a character, and each action class is only responsible for doing one thing. The code example in your answer still depends on a character attacking another character (target). What happens if you want to attack a building? Then you have to add (yet) another overload to Character.Attack method. IMHO better to have AttackCharacter and AttackBuilding inheriting from IAction.

Comment: @Si: (a) Verbs as names are a Bad Thing, as I already explained, (b) The objective of this question was to explain the SRP, not come up with a complete game design, and (c) what you're advocating is more like procedural programming than OOP. This single-minded obsession with one-method interfaces is cargo-cult programming; instead of thinking about cohesion, we just blindly follow rules, and we end up with senseless situations like a `BaseAttackBonus` class, which is really a procedure, implementing an indecipherably-named `IAction` interface; we end up with class bloat and schedule paralysis.

Comment: Quick, you better tell Microsoft, Apache and Eclipse that they're doing it wrong ;-) http://www.google.com/search?q=IAction I'm sorry you think I have an obsession with one method interfaces (I don't, but I do wear cargo pants if that helps:). Sure you may have high cohesion now with only one action, but what happens when your character needs more actions? And those actions all have their own unique requirements?

Comment: Apologies if that last comment sounds conceited. I understand where you're coming from (and agree with most of what you say), but my example was based on the behaviour of actions changing (as mentioned in the first sentence), which was probably the wrong approach to take.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that I'd really call that type of class SRP in the first place.  "Everything dealing with foo" is usually a sign that you're *not* following SRP (which is okay, it's not appropriate for all types of designs).

A good way of looking at SRP boundaries is "is there anything I can change about the class that would leave most of the class intact?"  If so, separate them out.  Or, to put it another way, if you touch one method in a class you should probably have to touch all of them.  One of the advantages of SRP is that it minimizes the scope of what you're touching when you make a change - if another file is untouched, you know you didn't add bugs to it!

Character classes in particular are at high degrees of danger of becoming God-classes in RPGs.  A possible way of avoiding this would be to approach this from a different way - start with your UI, and at each step, simply assert that the interfaces you wish existed *from the perspective of the class you're currently writing* existed already.  Also, look into the Inversion of Control principle and how design changes when using IoC (not necessarily an IoC container).

Answer (score 0):

The method that I go about when designing classes and which is what OO is based on is that an object models a real world object.

Let's take a look at Character...
Designing a Character class can be quite interesting.
It might be a contract
ICharacter
This means that anything that wants to be a character should be able to perform Walk(), Talk(), Attack(), Have some Properties such as Health, Mana.

You could then have a Wizard, a Wizard having special properties and the way he attacks is different than, let's say a Fighter.

I tend to not get too forced by Design Principles, but also think about modelling a real world object.